# Playing two inline videos at once via Cordova on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, aframe

I've built a 360 video player using A-Frame and Cordova, targeting iOS. The client now wants to add a sign language video in the corner to accompany the videos, for accessibility. Ordinarily, you could just embed the ASL video into the main video itself, but these are 360 videos in a 2D viewer so that's not really possible.

When I have both videos enabled (one A-Frame videosphere, one inline video tag), calling play() on the second one automatically pauses the other. The app works great without the ASL videos, but only plays one or the other with the two videos active.

Is there a way around this iOS limitation in Cordova apps? I've tried using an iframe to play the ASL video, but the same video limitation seems to be in place even in iframes.

It looks like there's a way to do it natively, but a full app rewrite would take way too long. Is there a way to bridge that for just the second video component? The ASL video is silent, but I imagine turning it into a gif will be horribly inefficient...

Comment: I suspect you may be able to modify one of the cordova plugins available for video players to handle the AVFoundation's multiple item playback.

Comment: I've got a basic plugin compiling and calling methods I can see via NSLog output, but I'm stuck on how to make the view appear in the UI hierarchy. The plugin is based on this post:

http://www.sdkboy.com/2011/07/video-on-the-iphone-tutorial-part-3-playing-multiple-videos-simultaneously/

I don't see many Cordova plugin examples that display inline UI elements, and my Objective-C is pretty rusty.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to handle something like this, so i'm not sure where to start. The way to think about this is that a Cordova webView is just that...a webView. You can size it however you want, position it however you want, etc. And, you can add as many Cordova webViews or native views as you want...mix and match. Same with native versus Cordova controllers. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still a work-in-progress, but I've got something functional here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/asl-player

Hope this can be helpful for others too.